# Best archiver library for iOS

Tags: ios, zip, archive, tar

I'm looking for an archiver library to use in my iOS app (zip or other formats). What is the best library in terms of:

1. How easy it is to include it in a iOS project
2. Memory consumption
3. Speed of unarchiving
4. How stable it is

Comment: Also: It's not clear if you want to archive objects (as in serialization) or if you want to compress files.

Comment: I want to use this to download folders from my server. So I only need and archiver to make sure an entire folder is downloaded (rather than downloading each file separately).

Comment: People who closed this question should burn in hell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [Objective Zip](https://github.com/AgileBits/objective-zip) and it worked quite well on iOS4. Work with this library is easy as this:

```
ZipFile *zipFile= [[ZipFile alloc] initWithFileName:@"test.zip" mode:ZipFileModeCreate];
ZipWriteStream *stream= [zipFile writeFileInZipWithName:@"abc.txt" compressionLevel:ZipCompressionLevelBest];
[stream writeData:abcData];
[stream finishedWriting];
```

Unzipping is done in similar fashion.

I can recommend it, but I can not provide any comparison to others. You can see on the wiki also some other libraries, which are based on this one. I hope this will help you a little.

Comment: Dead link, [objective-zip](https://github.com/AgileBits/objective-zip) seems to be located now in github

Comment: I used this a while back and thought it was great, I'm glad to see it's been improved since then!

Comment: this is modified copy of this library specifically for iOS/MacOS https://github.com/AgileBits/objective-zip

Answer (score 8):

For file archive, until now I found these libraries

- [zipzap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap)
- [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive)
- [Godzippa](https://github.com/mattt/Godzippa)
- [ZipArchive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive)
- [objective-zip](https://github.com/AgileBits/objective-zip)
- [GZIP](https://github.com/nicklockwood/GZIP)

(Naively sorted by todays *2013-04-16* github stars)

I only tried [ZipArchive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive) because I needed zip format and password protected archive creation. It seems to do the job pretty well until now.

Answer (score 4):

ZipZap is the solution I find most appealing. It has the advantage of only depending on the zlib the SDK provides.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use **zlib** directly.
No library dependency, just zlib, that you will probablity have in your project already

Look here [How to gzip Data in Memory Using Objective-C](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/how-to-gzip-data-in-memory-using-objective-c/)

Comment: zlib is only for compressing a single stream of bytes. The questio here is about a container for multiple files, and that's what RAR, PkZip etc. do, but zlib doesn't do that.