# How to minimize app size with heavy images in iOS Development?

Tags: ios, image

I am going to work on client application, in which he need to have whole app locally resources loading, and I have almost 70mb images files for iPad. I am going to start development soon but before that I need healthy suggestion and guidelines to reduce my app size with these images use locally. I don't want to make this heavy size like any 3d game? So I am looking for suggestion what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In similar scenarios I have found http://tinypng.org useful to compress the image file size without reducing quality.

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways:

1. zip all the image resources in the bundle. On first launch, extract that zip folder into documents directory and refer the image from there only. You will have to do it on first launch only.
2. create jpeg version of your images with some reduced quality. Apart from icon and splash, you can use jpeg version of images.
3. If possible, use 1 pixel width/height images for repetitive gradients.

Comment: Thanks @Apurv,Zip and unZip via coding? sorry didn't get you on your first point? Could you please explain?

Comment: yes.. you need not to do zip via coding.. you will need to unzip via coding...refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307737/best-archiver-library-for-ios

Comment: Thanks @Apurv nice detail for unzip from refer link. Again sorry for 3rd point how to use repetitive gradients?

Comment: the png format already does compressing, zipping will still have some effect but I wouldn't expect more than, say 10% size difference, I'd simply zip the folder in Finder first to make sure it's worth it before writing a lot of zip/unzip code

Comment: I mean if you are having a image with vertical gradient (color change will be observed in vertical direction and looks same in horizontal), you should have image width of 1 pixel only. In reverse case, u should have image height of 1 pixel only.